# Matching elements across datasets and replacing cell from one dataset with that of another

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dumbed down datasets, and want to replace the `1:70728:C:T` with `rs123456`.

```
a<- data.frame(ID=c(3,44),SNP=c("1:70728:C:T","1:612758:T:C "),effect_allele.outcome=c("C","T"), other_allele.outcome=c("T","C"), eaf.outcome=c(0.997843,0.993087), beta.outcome=c(0.03372300,-0.00728038), se.outcome=c(0.0250305, 0.0139970), pval.outcome=c(0.19,0.60), outcome=c("outcome","outcome"))


b <- data.frame(SNP=c("1:70728:C:T"), rsID=c("rs123456"))
```

I tried doing the following

```
library(dplyr)
insomnia_chr_pos %>%
  mutate(SNP = case_when((SNP==matched_mild$SNP) ~ matched_mild$rsid,
                         (SNP==matched_hosp$SNP) ~ matched_hosp$rsid,
                         (SNP==matched_sevr$SNP) ~ matched_sevr$rsid))
```

But I get this error:

`` Error in `mutate()`: ℹ In argument: `SNP = case_when(...)`. Caused by error in `case_when()`: ! Can't recycle `..1 (left)` (size 27697) to match `..1 (right)` (size 85). ``

the dataset with size 27697 corresponds with a, and the one size 85 corresponds with b.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you want to do is join the tables.

In your example this would mean doing a left join like so:

```r
joined <- a %>% 
  left_join(b, by = "SNP")
```

From your example code I understand that you want to join three tables and keep every match with SNP.

If the three tables have the same columns you can do a simply bind the rows together with:

```r
bind_rows(b, c, d)
```

Then you can do the join as above.

If they don't have the same columns, you can join all of them to insomnia_chr_pos and then create a new column with mutate where you keep every record from the three joined columns that is not NA.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to join the dataset and select the value from `b` dataset if it is present.

```
library(dplyr)

a |>
  left_join(b, by = join_by("SNP")) |>
  mutate(SNP = coalesce(rsID, SNP)) |>
  select(-rsID)

#  ID           SNP effect_allele.outcome other_allele.outcome eaf.outcome beta.outcome
#1  3      rs123456                     C                    T    0.997843   0.03372300
#2 44 1:612758:T:C                      T                    C    0.993087  -0.00728038

#  se.outcome pval.outcome outcome
#1  0.0250305         0.19 outcome
#2  0.0139970         0.60 outcome
```